# How do I solve this error of 'not all code paths return a value'?

Tags: c#, list, function, return

The name of the function is where the error is produced.  It states that 'not all code paths return a value'.  Why am I getting this error and how do I correct it?

```
public List<List<String>> getAvailablePMs()
{
    public List<List<String>> allAvailablePMs = new List<List<String>>;
    for (int s = 0; s < MyStaticValues.PMmanagerArray.Count; s++)
    { //for each PM in PMmanagerArray (excluding faulty or in-use)
        if (MyStaticValues.PMmanagerArray[s][1] == "" 
            && MyStaticValues.PMmanagerArray[s][2].Equals(0) 
            && MyStaticValues.PMmanagerArray[s][3].Equals(0))
        {//if the PM assigned bay is NULL AND PM status is not in use AND not faulty
            allAvailablePMs.push(MyStaticValues.PMmanagerArray[s][0]);
        }
        
    }
    return allAvailablePMs;
}
```

Comment: `allAvailablePMs.push` that is not how we add elements to a list in C#, there is no `push` method, there is an `Add`. Also, if `MyStaticValues.PMmanagerArray[s][0]` is a `string`, you can't add to `allAvailablePMs` since it expects a `List<string>`

Comment: You shouldn't use "public" when you declare a variable inside a method.

Comment: Intellisense is not as smart as a human. If you have multiple errors it may not be as good as human in finding the root case. Just go through all errors and see if you can fix either.

Comment: It is incredibly how much a misplaced `public` can confuse the compiler and the compiler does not even [complain](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wuDe43) about the public directly

Comment: Thankyou to all who commented, you helped me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use `public` inside a method, this is giving a compile error that is confusing the compiler, making it complain about "not all code paths returning a value".

Also, there are other erros on your code, there is no `push` method in `List`, you should use `Add`. Also, if `MyStaticValues.PMmanagerArray[s][0]` is a `string`, you can't add it to `allAvailablePMs`, since it expects a `List<string>`.

On a style note, it is a convention that all methods and properties in C# are PascalCase, not camelCase, so your method name should be `GetAvailablePMs`.